# My laravel project works great on xampp but when I try and run it using php artisan serve it times out

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I have a strange issue where I can run my Laravel project that uses mysql  perfectly when using xamp php 7.2  , So normally if it runs well in xampp  it  should run well if I just decide to use  php artisan serve and access it via  http://127.0.0.1:8000/    But to my surprise it doesn't'.

If I use php artisan serve  the debug message I get from my Laravel project is

```
 Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
  Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded
```

I tried giving full permissions to all folders as well as run the following commands:

```
composer update
composer dump-auto-load
php artisan serve
```

Any one else experience this strange issue?  Where it works perfect in xampp  but if you `cd` to the project directory and run `php artisan serve`, it just times out.

Comment: Have you gone through all of the steps on the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/installation#server-requirements) that speaks to configuration and setup of your server?

Comment: Do you get this same behavior in a fresh, untouched, brand-new Laravel install?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the PHP's default web server (eg. `php artisan serve`) you need to restart your server after any changing your ***php.ini*** file values.

Answer (score -1):

Try to run in a different port.

```
php artisan serve --port=8080
```

and if still doesn't work, set time limit to your controller, in __contruct function,

```
  public function __construct()
  {
    set_time_limit(300);
  }
```

Comment: Port shouldn't matter. Changing the time limit won't fix the underlying problem of OP's pageviews taking more than 60 seconds to execute.

Answer (score -1):

This problem is occering due to maximum execution time defined on php configuration.  As common factor please use following:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
```

Add the above lines at the top of your server.php file.

Comment: This won't fix the underlying problem of OP's pageviews taking more than 60 seconds to execute.